# Auto-adjust an image height depending on

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In a bootstrap grid, I have one column containing a rectangle image beside two columns containing two squares images. The rectangle image height is equal to two square images height (and the widths are the same).
Each case containing an image has this style (and the col-xs-12 class):

```
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
```

And each image has this:

```
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
```

This vertical gap caused by the padding-bottom make the column containing the rectangle image to not end at the same level:

**scheme**:
[image: scheme]

I tried to give this style to the rectangle image (to stretch it a little):

```
height: calc(100% + 20px);
```

(it would probably not be sufficient because of the padding-right that also alter proportions of the images)

But it doesn't change anything. Strangely, when I give it a height in % like height: 10% or height 110% that displays the image to its true height but not to the height of the container. I know height in % is tricky, but well, do you have any solution to fix the height of the rectangle image, to make it fit the height of the column before?

thanks!

PS : like asked, the html code :

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6 text-sm-left">
            <div class="col-xs-12 moodboard-image-item ">
               <a href="http://fr.lipsum.com/feed/html" class="contains-image-with-overlay">
                  <picture>
                     <source class="img-responsive" srcset="/sites/mysite/files/2018-01/image-mobile-moodboardimg/industriel-mobile_1.jpg" media="(max-width: 767px)">
                     <source class="img-responsive" srcset="/sites/mysite/files/2018-01/image-desktop-moodboardimg/industriel-desktop_1.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)">
                     <img class="img-responsive" src="/sites/mysite/files/2018-01/image-desktop-moodboardimg/industriel-desktop_1.jpg" alt="Industriel" data-pin-nopin="1">
                  </picture>
                  <div class="moodboard-image-title bg-moodboard-title-black">
                     Industriel
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 text-sm-center">
            <div class="col-xs-12 moodboard-image-item ">
               <a href="http://fr.lipsum.com/feed/html" class="contains-image-with-overlay">
                  <picture>
                     <source class="img-responsive" srcset="/sites/mysite/files/2018-01/image-mobile-moodboardimg/classique-chic-mobile_0.jpg" media="(max-width: 767px)">
                     <source class="img-responsive" srcset="/sites/mysite/files/2018-01/image-desktop-moodboardimg/classique-chic-desktop_0.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)">
                     <img class="img-responsive" src="/sites/mysite/files/2018-01/image-desktop-moodboardimg/classique-chic-desktop_0.jpg" alt="Classique chic" data-pin-nopin="1">
                  </picture>
                  <div class="moodboard-image-title bg-moodboard-title-black">
                     Classique chic
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12 text-sm-left">
            <div class="col-xs-12 moodboard-image-item ">
               <a href="http://fr.lipsum.com/feed/html" class="contains-image-with-overlay">
                  <picture>
                     <source class="img-responsive" srcset="/sites/mysite/files/2018-01/image-mobile-moodboardimg/vintage-mobile_0.jpg" media="(max-width: 767px)">
                     <source class="img-responsive" srcset="/sites/mysite/files/2018-01/image-desktop-moodboardimg/vintage-desktop_0.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)">
                     <img class="img-responsive" src="/sites/mysite/files/2018-01/image-desktop-moodboardimg/vintage-desktop_0.jpg" alt="Vintage" data-pin-nopin="1">
                  </picture>
                  <div class="moodboard-image-title bg-moodboard-title-black">
                     Vintage
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 text-sm-right">
      <div class="col-xs-12 moodboard-image-item adjust-height-to-gaps">
         <a href="http://fr.lipsum.com/feed/html" class="contains-image-with-overlay">
            <picture>
               <source class="img-responsive" srcset="/sites/mysite/files/2018-01/image-mobile-moodboardimg/modern-design-mobile_0.jpg" media="(max-width: 767px)">
               <source class="img-responsive" srcset="/sites/mysite/files/2018-01/image-desktop-moodboardimg/modern-design-desktop_0.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)">
               <img class="img-responsive" src="/sites/mysite/files/2018-01/image-desktop-moodboardimg/modern-design-desktop_0.jpg" alt="Moderne design" data-pin-nopin="1">
            </picture>
            <div class="moodboard-image-title bg-moodboard-title-black">
               Moderne design
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will you be able to post the whole html code of this section?

Comment: Is it an option to set the image as a `background-image`?

Comment: No background-image due to SEO